# openOrCreateDatabase doesn't work

Tags: android, database, nullpointerexception

I need help.
I have a ListView with a custom Adapter, when in this ListView i have a CheckBox and in onClick method should update a table in my database.
My onClick method of my CheckBox is implemented in my Adapter Class, and when a i click in some CheckBox, i call a method of my other class when i create my ListView.

In my Adapter Classe

#

```
chkQuitado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
    ViewMovimentos vm = new ViewMovimentos();

    int movId = Integer.parseInt(entry.getMovId());
    if(cb.isChecked()){
     vm.confirmaQuitacao(context, movId); //Implementada na classe ViewMovimentos
    }else{
     vm.desfazQuitacao(context, movId); //Implementada na classe ViewMovimentos
   }
  }
});
```

#

In my Movimentos.class i implements my methods confirmaQuitacao() and desfazQuitacao()

#

```
public void confirmaQuitacao(Context context, final int movId){
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   builder.setMessage("Confirma a quitação deste movimento?");
   builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       quitaMovimento(movId, MOV_FECHADO);
   }
});
builder.setNeutralButton("Não", null);


builder.setTitle("Aviso");
builder.show();
}

public void desfazQuitacao(Context context, final int movId){
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Deseja marcar esse movimento como não quitado?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     quitaMovimento(movId, MOV_ABERTO);
    }
});
builder.setNeutralButton("Não", null);


builder.setTitle("Aviso");
builder.show();
}
```

#

When this two methods call the quitaMovimento method.

#

```
public void quitaMovimento(int movId, int quitar){
   SQLiteDatabase banco = openOrCreateDatabase(nmBanco, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);

   ContentValues camposPar = new ContentValues();
   camposPar.put("movQuitado", quitar);
   banco.update("movimentos", camposPar, "movId = "+movId, null);

   localizaRegistros();
}
```

#

So, when i call the openOrCreateDatabase() happens a force close in my application, and the logcat show the error below.

#

```
02-14 22:47:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(367): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at com.simpatico.sgf.ViewMovimentos.quitaMovimento(ViewMovimentos.java:433)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at com.simpatico.sgf.ViewMovimentos$7.onClick(ViewMovimentos.java:450)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-14 22:47:33.749: E/AndroidRuntime(367): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

#

Someone can help me with this problem?

Thank's

Comment: as you can see there's a `NullPointerException` meaning that you're supplying either a wrong parameter or your ContextWrapper is null. Does your DB  class extend the SQLiteDatabase class? perhaps you should use  `openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)` instead of  `openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)`

Comment: sorry but your code in spanish is unreadable. you should write in english. it will be easiest to debug for other  people.

Comment: nmBanco is a variable contains my database name

Comment: did you try to use another method without ErrorHandler?

Comment: As I wrote openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) without the ErrorHandler parameter

Comment: I nerver used ErrorHandler. How can i do this?

Comment: You supplied null as ErrorHandler in the call `openOrCreateDatabase(nmBanco, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Some arguments to `openOrCreateDatabase` are documented as optional, but that does not mean that you can pass `null` for those; it means that you should use overloads where you do not pass these arguments at all.

Here is one syntax that will work for you:

```
SQLiteDatabase banco = openDatabase(nmBanco, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY)
```